# Why is urlparse.urlenparse works inconsistent?

Tags: python, urlparse

When netloc is empty urlparse.urlunparse is inconsistent:

```
>>> urlparse.urlunparse(('http','','test_path', None, None, None))
'http:///test_path'
>>> urlparse.urlunparse(('ftp','','test_path', None, None, None))
'ftp:///test_path'
>>> urlparse.urlunparse(('ssh','','test_path', None, None, None))
'ssh:test_path'
```

Is it a bug or a feature? 
I would expect urlunparse to behave always, as in first example, even if scheme is not recognized.

Comment: The urlparse source code is missing 'ssh', at least as of 2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data` tuple you are passing to `urlunparse` has the following components:

```
scheme, netloc, url, query, fragment = data
```

When there is no `netloc`, and the `scheme` is not in `uses_netloc`, the url is

```
    url = scheme + ':' + url
```

That is the way urlunparse (which calls urlunsplit) [is defined](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/940748853712/Lib/urllib/parse.py#l386):

```
def urlunsplit(data):
    ...
    scheme, netloc, url, query, fragment = data
    if netloc or (scheme and scheme in uses_netloc and url[:2] != '//'):
        if url and url[:1] != '/': url = '/' + url
        url = '//' + (netloc or '') + url
    if scheme:
        url = scheme + ':' + url
```

---

Note that `'ssh'` is not in `uses_netloc`:

```
uses_netloc = ['ftp', 'http', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'telnet',
               'imap', 'wais', 'file', 'mms', 'https', 'shttp',
               'snews', 'prospero', 'rtsp', 'rtspu', 'rsync', '',
               'svn', 'svn+ssh', 'sftp','nfs','git', 'git+ssh']
```

---

You do get a url that begins with `ssh://` if you supply a `netloc`:

```
In [140]: urlparse.urlunparse(('ssh','netloc','test_path', None, None, None))
Out[140]: 'ssh://netloc/test_path'
```

Comment: So If I understand correctly to change the behaviour I could use urlparse.uses_netloc.append('ssh'). Is that correct?

Comment: Eek, no. I am not up an URL specifications. I know for certain I know less about the specs than the designers of the urlparse module. So I would not recommend changing `uses_netloc`.